# legitimate memory pages that are marked as RWX?

Tags: x86, memory, binary

In windows and linux x86 (including x86_64) world, is there any legitimate binary (i.e., a program binary generated by the typical compiling-assembling-linking flow and no manual editing on binary after it is generated) that will have RWX memory pages after being loaded? If yes, what are the use cases?

Comment: operating system? compiler? binary format?

Comment: OS: linux, windows. Compiler: gcc, visual studio, binary: ELF.

Comment: ELF binaries won't be executed by a windows kernel and ELF segment permissions are denoted RWE rather than RWX

Comment: what does it mean for a binary to be considered "legitimate"?

Comment: @SYS_V, a program binary generated by the typical compiling-linking-assembling flow, i.e., no manual editing on binary after it is generated.

Comment: the correct order is compilation, assembly, then linking. All of this information needs to be conveyed in the question

Comment: @SYS_V, yes, yes. I have updated it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: this answer corresponds to the [original question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/15270/1)*

Process segment permissions may vary across architectures and implementations. For example, it is expected that on more recent x86 Linux systems that GCC creates binaries with non-executable stacks. In contrast with this, it used to be the case that MIPS did not even support an non-executable stack - in other words, *every* MIPS binary had its stack permissions set to RWE.

> MIPS floating point support requires that any instruction that cannot
>   be directly executed by the FPU, be emulated by the kernel.  Part of
>   this emulation involves executing non-FPU instructions that fall in
>   the delay slots of FP branch instructions.  **Since the beginning of
>   MIPS/Linux time, this has been done by placing the instructions on the
>   userspace thread stack, and executing them there**, as the instructions
>   must be executed in the MM context of the thread receiving the
>   emulation.
>
> Because of this, **the de facto MIPS Linux userspace ABI requires that
>   the userspace thread have an executable stack**.  It is de facto,
>   because it is not written anywhere that this must be the case, but it
>   is never the less a requirement.<sup>[[1]](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/5039371/)</sup>

A kernel patch had to be developed in order to support MIPS executable stack protection:

> The following series implements an executable stack protection in MIPS.
>
> It sets up a per-thread 'VDSO' page and appropriate TLB support.
>   Page is set write-protected from user and is maintained via kernel VA.
>   MIPS FPU emulation is shifted to new page and stack is relieved for
>   execute protection as is as all data pages in default setup during ELF
>   binary initialization. The real protection is controlled by GLIBC and
>   it can do stack protected now as it is done in other architectures and
>   I learned today that GLIBC team is ready for this.
>
> Note: actual execute-protection depends from HW capability, of course.
>
> This patch is required for MIPS32/64 R2 emulation on MIPS R6 architecture.<sup>[[2]](https://lwn.net/Articles/653708/)</sup>

Here is a concrete example, using a MIPS ELF binary from a ZTE router:

```
$ file cspd 
cspd: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0, stripped
```

Note the permissions of segment `GNU_STACK`:

```
$ readelf -l cspd 

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x59d790
There are 8 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000034 0x00400034 0x00400034 0x00100 0x00100 R E 0x4
  INTERP         0x000134 0x00400134 0x00400134 0x00014 0x00014 R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0]
  REGINFO        0x000148 0x00400148 0x00400148 0x00018 0x00018 R   0x4
  LOAD           0x000000 0x00400000 0x00400000 0x1ef050 0x1ef050 R E 0x10000
  LOAD           0x1ef050 0x005ff050 0x005ff050 0x148e2 0x2a070 RW  0x10000
  DYNAMIC        0x000160 0x00400160 0x00400160 0x00130 0x00130 RWE 0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RWE 0x4    <---
  NULL           0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000     0x4

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .reginfo 
   03     .interp .reginfo .dynamic .hash .dynsym .dynstr .init .text .MIPS.stubs .fini .rodata 
   04     .data.rel.ro .data .rld_map .got .sbss .bss 
   05     .dynamic 
   06     
   07
```

---

<sub>1. [Patchwork MIPS: Allow FPU emulator to use non-stack area.](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/5039371/)</sub>

<sub>2. [MIPS executable stack protection](https://lwn.net/Articles/653708/)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not realize the question is so broad. I am only interested in the case for x86. Optionally, if you know something about ARM, that would be great. But I am OK with x86 only use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Just-In-Time Compilation support could be one reason for pages to be legitimately marked RWX.  In iOS MobileSafari is one of a small number of Apple apps that has a "dynamic codesigning" entitlement which allows for the RWX pages to be mapped.  Despite the potential danger, JavaScript performance is too important to not have these pages.  This makes Safari a desirable target for exploits.  For more information on a recent iOS exploit that attacked Safari for its RWX pages read the [Pegasus Technical Report](https://info.lookout.com/rs/051-ESQ-475/images/pegasus-exploits-technical-details.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

It seems some .NET native binaries, e.g. `System.ni.dll` [have an RWX `.xdata` section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448065/risks-of-rwx-memory-pages), although I believe they're not generated by a normal compilation workflow (they're produced by `ngen` AFAIK) so they're probably not covered by the current version of the question.